# JQuery DataTable Plugin Width issues

Tags: jquery, datatable, width

I am using jQuery datatable plugin. I am rendering my html table first and then applying the plugin. It has some issues.

Issues:

1. Header column and body columns are not aligned.
2. If there are a lot of columns (columns are generated dynamically not possible to set a fix width of columns) the data table grows horizontally.

**Sample Code :**

```
var scrollY = $(window).height() * 80 / 100;   
var oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable({
    "sScrollX": "100%",
    "sScrollY": scrollY,
    "bScrollCollapse": true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bStateSave": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "bSort": true,
    "aaSorting": []       
});

oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
```

This is how my table is looking
[image]

As you can see header and body are not aligned, table is expanding to the right of screen.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**
I am using this plugin inside JQuery tabs.

Comment: datatable uses same table for header and body, hence this should not happend. Are you using `<head></head>` and `<body></body>` tags in your table? can you share the html code also.

Comment: Yes I am using <thead> and <body> tags. Actually this html is generated in js code so can not share easily.

Comment: See [this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/16512/fnadjustcolumnsizing-and-fixedcolumns) if useful to you

Answer (score 1):

First I would control the html structure before creating the datatable. It has to be like the following:

```
<table id="myTable">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    // exact number of th present in the datatable
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

then i would try to set:

```
"bAutoWidth": true
```

even if it's difficult to solve your problem without HTML code...

Comment: My HTML code is exactly like this. I can copy the complete table HTML though.